# How do I check which Swing component is being passed as a parameter?

Tags: java, swing

I have a method here (below) that, in itself, works very well.
The problem is I want to change it's behavior based on which JTable is passed through the parameter.

For example, right now I have two JTables, table1 and table 2.  I want to set up an if statement that says if (table == table1){...} else if (table == table2){...}

The problem is no matter what I try (comparing hash codes, comparing the e.source to the component, the source hashcode to the table1.hashcode() etc.) I can't get it to register when the table that is passed is in fact table1.

**Is there a way to compare components in this way? (Again, confirming which JTable 'table' (the JTable passed in the parameters) is; 'table1' or 'table2'.**

Here's my code:

```
 public TableCellEditor myCellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField()) {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        delegate.setValue((editorComponent instanceof JTextField) ? null : value);
                myCellEditor.addCellEditorListener(
            new CellEditorListener() {
                public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
                }

                public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
                    //if (table == table1){...} 
                }
            });
        return editorComponent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know on what table did the even fired? Then use `e.getSource();` If you want to see if tableX and tableY are similar then you need to write a  [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) . [This](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) example may help a bit. Generally Comparators are handy and quite easy to implement.

Try to avoid the

```
 new CellEditorListener() {
                public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
                }

                public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
                    //if (table == table1){...} 
                }
            });
```

Instead create 2 `CellEditors` and assign your listener to each..

```
myCellEditor1.addCellEditorListener(listener);
myCellEditor2.addCellEditorListener(listener);


//Now by accessing e.getSource you know which celleditor fired!


CellEditorListener listener= new CellEditorListener() {
                public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
                }

                public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
                   if (e.getSource()==myCellEditor1)
else if (e.getSource()==myCellEditor2)

                }
            });
```

Comment: How do I compare e.getSource() to table1/table2? The hashes never match regardless of which one triggered the action

Comment: To get it right.. You got 1 cell editor in 2 tables, and your problem is which table fires the editevent right?

Comment: Why then dont you create one for each table?

Comment: Well, they're meant to be exactly the same, and are added in the exact same place, so I just referenced the code where they are added and passed them through a parameter. Basically, my intent is to minimize repetitive code